# action of an ismorphic tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, lie-groups, lie-algebras

classical example that I see a lot and don't understand (this one from Lie groups and Lie algebra):

$T_0\mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ (denote the isomorphism as $\phi:T_0\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$)

$X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$L_g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n : x \mapsto g+x$

${L_g}_{*h}(X) = \frac{d}{dt}(g+h+tX)\vert_0 = X$

My question his how do we calculate ${L_g}_{*h}(X)$? Normally ${L_g}_{*h}(X)$ is from $T_0\mathbb{R}^n$ to $T_0\mathbb{R}^n$. So how is this calculated properly?

Is it in fact an abuse of notation? it should actually be ${L_g}_{*h}(\phi^{-1}(X))$

Also $T_0\mathbb{R}^n$ acts on fonctions, but how does this action translate to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Any help would welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In fact $T\mathbb R^n$ is "really" $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n$. In the sense that there exists a canonical isomorphism between them. (It's a bit silly but also an important exercise to do.)

To compute ${L_g}_*$ you just have to compute a differential as usual. The fact that $$ L_g(x) = x+g $$shows you that $$ L_g(x + h) = (x+h)+g = (x+g) +h = L_g(x) + h $$
so its differential is just the identity.

Ok, now, I choose a base $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for $\mathbb R^n$. Let's take a vector field
$$ V = \sum a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $$
the isomorphism $T\mathbb R^n\cong \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n $ is given by $$ V\mapsto (a_1,\dots,a_n)=: W. $$
If $f\in C^\infty(M)$ then $$ V(f) = \sum a_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \left\langle (a_1,\dots,a_n), \left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)\right\rangle = \langle W, df\rangle  .$$
And I think this last expression is what you are looking for.

Comment: $T_0\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of tangent vectors to $\mathbb{R}^n$ at the point $0$. Therefore it is the set of linear operators respecting Leibniz identity from $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. So what is your question here ?

Comment: $T_0\mathbb{R}^n\cong \mathbb{R}^n$ so I suppose there is some sort of "translation" of the action of an element. If $X\in T_0\mathbb{R}^n$ then $X(f)$ makes sense. How do we make sense of $\phi(X)(f)$?

Comment: I edited my answer, is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: As an aside, it makes sense to distinguish between row and column vectors. Elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are columns, and $\mathrm{d}f$ is a row.

Comment: That's sugar. In fact a vector isn't either column or raw. This distinction is appropriate when we are talking in terms of matrices, but that's not the case. (A vector is just a vector, and a scalar product is well defined for vectors...)